# Bash script - Not able to execute command with special characters stored in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, curl

In my bash script,
I store a curl command in a variable:

```
MYCOMMAND="curl -n https://gerrit.myCompany.com/a/changes/?q=project:xyzProject+branch:master+ownerin:abcGroup\"&\"n=20"
```

Note that the query needs to be appended with **"&"n=someNumber** in order to limit the number of results returned by the gerrit server.

Now if I echo my variable everything seems fine:

```
echo "my command is " $MYCOMMAND
my command is  curl -n https://gerrit.myCompany.com/a/changes/?q=project:xyzProject+branch:master+ownerin:abcGroup"&"n=20
```

Infact if I copy this output and directly paste it in the script OR give it on the command prompt it works very well and I get my required gerrit query output

But if I run it directly from the variable it throws error `"--"n" is not a valid option`

```
$MYCOMMAND
"--"n" is not a valid option
```

I am very much puzzled by this behavior. Can someone help?

Comment: Check this: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: I copied your command into a script and was able to execute the command exactly as you tried.  No error for me.  I have curl version 7.54.0.

Comment: You might want to try `eval $MYCOMMAND` as a different way of executing the curl command.

Comment: @EJK Please don't use or recommend `eval` for this sort of thing -- it's a massive bug magnet.